# How to display a graph on TensorBoard

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I just want to display a simple graph on TensorBoard:
[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4PHN.png)

I tried:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(2, dtype=tf.float32, name='tensor_a')
b = tf.constant(3, dtype=tf.float32, name='tensor_b')
c = tf.add(a,b)
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('/content/grafo1')
tf.summary.write('test',c)

import tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir=grafo1
```

Using Colab.

But: "No dashboards are active for the current data set."

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't see the graph if eager execution enabled.

You can achieve your goal with the following code:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

tf.disable_eager_execution()

a = tf.constant(2, dtype=tf.float32, name='tensor_a')
b = tf.constant(3, dtype=tf.float32, name='tensor_b')
c = tf.add(a,b)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/content/grafo1', graph=tf.get_default_graph())
writer.flush()

import tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir=grafo1
```